# JQuery for loop - function with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, loops

Is there a way to turn this into a for loop? I have to run this code 114 time and am looking for a way to simplify this. The numbers on the class name would be the variable. The next one would be .select3 etc...

```
$('.select2').click(function () {
        if ($('.saved_list .thumb2').length == 0 && $('.saved > li').length < totalPic)
            {
                $(this).parent().clone().appendTo('.saved_list ul');
                $('.saved .select2').replaceWith('<div class="remove2">Remove</div>');
                $('.saved a').contents().unwrap(); 
            } else {
                alert ('You can only choose 3 paintings');  
            }
            if ($('.saved_list li').has('.thumb2')) {
                $(".select2 .img-swap").attr("src", "images/check_on.gif");
            } else {
                $(".select2 .img-swap").attr("src", "images/check_off.gif");
        };
    });
```

Comment: no need for a loop.. just make it more flexible.. show your html

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to give them all a common class name, then you could just use a single selector for all of them?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var run_select = function(index){
    var selector = '.select'+index;
    $(selector).click(function () {
        if ($('.saved_list .thumb2').length == 0 && $('.saved > li').length < totalPic)
        {
            $(this).parent().clone().appendTo('.saved_list ul');
            $('.saved '+selector).replaceWith('<div class="remove2">Remove</div>');
            $('.saved a').contents().unwrap(); 
        } else {
            alert ('You can only choose 3 paintings');  
        }
        if ($('.saved_list li').has('.thumb2')) {
            $(selector+" .img-swap").attr("src", "images/check_on.gif");
        } else {
            $(selector+" .img-swap").attr("src", "images/check_off.gif");
        };
    });
};
var i, l = 114;
for(i=1;i<=114;i++){
    run_select(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, simplify html if you can. Use id for unique identifiers and the same name for css classes. Like this:

```
<div id='select2' class='select'></div>
```

Then use `.each()` if you want to get all your items:

```
$('.select').each(function() {
    // use $(this) here to refer to the current item
});
```

But in your case, you can simply apply the 'click' event like this:

```
$('.select').click(function(e) {
       // use $(this) or $(e.target) here to refer to the current item
       // if you need to get the id number you could get it from the id
       // (supposing has id='select2')

       var id = $(this).attr('id').substring(6); // it returns 2
});
```